# What is the easiest way to implement trivial forum in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I am building an Umbraco site, and there is a need for a *really* simple forum (e.g. one level of topics, a simple subject/body form for new entries and replies, that's about it)

What is the easiest way to implement this? I think nForum is an overkill. Should I go with Umbraco API for member management and content creation, of should I use my own prefixed db tables and custom backend implementation?

Thanks in advance
Themos

Answer (score 0):

For small and limited requirements you can surely look at the UFORUM, it is time tested and pretty decent.

It supports membership out of the box...

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/uforum-basics

Check it out Hope it helps.